# Sequential number generation with etcd cluster

Tags: go, distribution, scaling, etcd, id-generation

I am exploring etcd to implement a sequential number generator for distributed environment. My requirement is to generate non repeating sequential number to be used in each request for multiple instances of same application. And there can be n such application with the requirement. I did POC for this in multiple ways using STM and mutex locks provided in [golang client packages](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3/concurrency)

With a single node etcd server (Will be atleast 3 node cluster for RAFT to work in production) in local machine setup I wrote a simple program to generate ids(numbers) in 500 goroutines. Each routine gets 10 ids each and thus a total of 5000 ids. With time stats, STM with retry attempts performs better than mutex locks. Apart from these approaches, is there any better options to achieve sequential number generation? Can etcd be used for this purpose in the first place?

PS: I am attaching the code sample just for reference. I don't expect it to be reviewed. My concern is just the correct approach to generate sequential numbers with etcd

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"

    CONC "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/concurrency"

    "github.com/golang/glog"
    ETCD "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
)

var client *ETCD.Client
var deadline = 200 * time.Second

func main() {
    var err error
    client, err = ETCD.New(ETCD.Config{
        Endpoints: []string{"127.0.0.1:2379"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln("err:", err)
        return
    }
    idGen := &SeqIDGenerator{key: "_id"}

    err = func() error {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
        defer cancel()
        _, err = client.Put(ctx, idGen.key, strconv.FormatInt(0, 10))
        return err
    }()
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln("err:", err)
        return
    }
    id, err := idGen.nextWithMutex()
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln("err:", err)
        return
    }
    glog.Errorln("done", id)
    id, err = idGen.nextWithSTMSerialiazable()
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln("err:", err)
        return
    }
    glog.Errorln("done", id)
    // st := time.Now()
    // stressSTMSerialiazableSeq(idGen)
    // glog.Errorln(time.Since(st))

}

type SeqIDGenerator struct {
    key string
}

func (idGen *SeqIDGenerator) nextWithSTMSerialiazable() (int64, error) {

    var retrived int64
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), deadline)
    defer cancel()
    var err error
    retry := retry
    for retry > 0 {
        retry--
        stmresp, err := CONC.NewSTMSerializable(ctx, client, func(s CONC.STM) error {
            v := s.Get(idGen.key)
            retrived, err = strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            retrived++
            s.Put(idGen.key, strconv.FormatInt(retrived, 10))
            return nil
        })
        if err != nil {
            continue
        } else if stmresp.Succeeded {
            return retrived, nil
        }

    }
    return 0, errors.New("ID gen failed. Retry exceeded")
}

func (idGen *SeqIDGenerator) nextWithMutex() (int64, error) {
    s, err := CONC.NewSession(client) // explore options to pass
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    m := CONC.NewMutex(s, idGen.key)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), deadline)
    defer cancel()
    m.Lock(ctx)
    defer m.Unlock(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Get(ctx, idGen.key)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    retrived, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(resp.OpResponse().Get().Kvs[0].Value), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    retrived++
    _, err = client.Put(ctx, idGen.key, strconv.FormatInt(retrived, 10))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return retrived, nil
}

func (idGen *SeqIDGenerator) nextWithSTMReapeatable() (int64, error) {

    var retrived int64
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), deadline)
    defer cancel()
    var err error
    retry := retry
    for retry > 0 {
        retry--
        stmresp, err := CONC.NewSTMRepeatable(ctx, client, func(s CONC.STM) error {
            v := s.Get(idGen.key)
            retrived, err = strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            retrived++
            s.Put(idGen.key, strconv.FormatInt(retrived, 10))
            return nil
        })
        if err != nil {
            continue
        } else if stmresp.Succeeded {
            return retrived, nil
        }

    }
    return 0, errors.New("ID gen failed. Retry exceeded")
}

var n int = 500
var retry int = 40 // move as conf

func stressMutex(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                _, err := idGen.nextWithMutex()
                if err != nil {
                    glog.Errorln("err:", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()

}

func stressMutexSeq(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            _, err := idGen.nextWithMutex()
            if err != nil {
                glog.Errorln("err:", err)
            }
        }
    }

}

func stressSTMSerialiazableSeq(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            _, err := idGen.nextWithSTMSerialiazable()
            if err != nil {
                glog.Errorln("err:", err)
            }
        }
    }

}

func stressSTMReapeatableSeq(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            _, err := idGen.nextWithSTMReapeatable()
            if err != nil {
                glog.Errorln("err:", err)
            }
        }
    }

}

func stressSTMSerialiazable(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(n)
    var success int64
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                _, err := idGen.nextWithSTMSerialiazable()
                if err != nil {
                    glog.Errorln("err:", err)
                } else {
                    atomic.AddInt64(&success, 1)
                }

            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    glog.Errorln("success:", success)

}

func stressSTMReapeatable(idGen *SeqIDGenerator) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(n)
    var success int64
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                _, err := idGen.nextWithSTMReapeatable()
                if err != nil {
                    glog.Errorln("err:", err)
                } else {
                    atomic.AddInt64(&success, 1)
                }

            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    glog.Errorln("success:", success)

}
```

Comment: Could you add an example what receiver side of the app would see?

Comment: Consider a social network app which requires unique ID for each user and the application decides to use sequential numbers for ID. The app will first acquire a ID generator from the ID generator service with an unique key (say "social_network_user_id") and it will request new ID from the service with the key for each new user added.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking at this myself. Here are two possible ways to do this:
(I'm newer at etcd, so caveat emptor)

1. If you can live with unique monotonic values *with big gaps*, you can use the etcd cluster "Revision", this gets incremented every time you modify the store: put a key, etc.
   (This value is returned from put ops in mature etcd clients)

```
$ etcdctl put k v -w json
{"header":{"cluster_id":14841639068965178418,"member_id":10276657743932975437,"revision":8,"raft_term":3}}
```

Use the value returned for "revision" in your client. This should effectively be an
atomic operation that generates a unique value (globally) for the client invoking 'put'.

2. If you need unique sequential values without gaps, it looks like you can use the "mod_revision" value associated with each key.
   It is per-key, and gets incremented after each put.
   It gets reset to zero when you delete the key.

Try this:

```
$ etcdctl put k v --prev-kv -w json
{"header":{"cluster_id":14841639068965178418,"member_id":10276657743932975437,"revision":10,"raft_term":3},"prev_kv":{"key":"aw==","create_revision":8,"mod_revision":8,"version":1,"value":"dg=="}}
```

Again, the value returned for "mod_revision" in your client.
This depends upon 'prev-kv' being atomic WRT 'put', such that any 'put'+'prev-key'
forms an atomic operation. I believe this to be so, but don't have a citation.

How are my rules on how to decide between the two:

1. If I can accept unique values with gaps, use the global "revision",
   it can't be reset to zero unless you start with a new KV store.
   This is my prefered method, as this can't be accidentally reset.
2. If you must have unique sequential values, use the per-key "mod_revision".
   But be aware if you somehow accidentally delete the k/v for tracking mod_revision,
   the serial number will start at zero! This could cause big problems for you. But the advantage here is you can have multiple sequential unique serial numbers.